# json array/object iteration in java android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Hi Guys [new to Java and Android]

I have a php script which gives out an json response like this

```
echo json_encode(array($camparray));
```

The json array is like this

```
[
    {
        "0":{"url":"10007.jpg","cmpname":"Romain Jerome"},
        "2":{"url":"10023.jpg","cmpname":"NGO"},
        "3":{"url":"10024.jpg","cmpname":"Save The Children"},
        "4":{"url":"10039.jpg","cmpname":"John Deere"},
        "5":{"url":"10039.jpg","cmpname":"Starbucks"}
    }
]
```

Now I am using volley to get the response. I am somehow not able to iterate the array at all. Please help..

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"On Response Try block",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        JSONArray camps = response.getJSONArray("camparray");
        // insert for loop here...
        //String pinusers = response.getString("mobileno");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"On Response Try block"+pinusers,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(camps!= null){
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("camps");
            JSONArray cmpz = jsonObj.getJSONArray("camparray");
            for (int i = 0; i < cmpz.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = cmpz.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString("url");
                String name = c.getString("cmpname");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"On Response Try bitch"+id+name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Camp NULL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Try Fail NULL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I dont understand why its been hours and I am not able to crack it. Some concept issue I guess...

Answer (score 0):

First, your response from server is in a wrong structured format. Still, to get the contents of this response, you can use this :

```
  if(camps!= null){
        JSONArray cmpz = new JSONArray("camparray");
        JSONObject jsonObj = cmpz.getJSONObject(0);

        String zero = jsonObj.getString("0");
        JSONObject vZero = new JSONObject(zero);
        String zeroUrl = vZero.getString("url");
        String cmpnameZero = vZero.getString("cmpname");

        String two = jsonObj.getString("2");
        JSONObject vTwo = new JSONObject(two);
        String twoUrl = vTwo.getString("url");
        String cmpnameTwo = vTwo.getString("cmpname");



        String three = jsonObj.getString("3");
        JSONObject vThree = new JSONObject(three);
        String threeUrl = vThree.getString("url");
        String cmpnamTthree = vThree.getString("cmpname");

        //Similarly get value for 4 and 5 and do whatever you want with those variables
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Basu Singh my values in json are not fixed...now there are 2 next iteration it could be 20.

Comment: Please provide the whole response you are receiving from the server.

Comment: basu hi

Now that is todays response. Tommorow will be 
[
 {
  "0":{"url":"10007.jpg","cmpname":"Romain Jerome"},
  "2":{"url":"10023.jpg","cmpname":"NGO"},
  "3":{"url":"10024.jpg","cmpname":"Save The Children"},
  "4":{"url":"10039.jpg","cmpname":"John Deere"},
  "5":{"url":"10039.jpg","cmpname":"Starbucks"}
                "6":{"url":"10039.jpg","cmpname":"Starbucks"}
                 "7":{"url":"10039.jpg","cmpname":"Starbucks"}
 }
]

Comment: i need to get array. lenght and iterate through that as well.

Comment: First, these are Json Object. You can use length() for length. Now, what your server give is JSON Objects which is structured as name : value. So to get the value, you have to know the name. The name here are 0, 2, 3, 4..... So, it's important to use these names to get the data. A more convenient way is to modify your server for giving proper response.